# Regexp to find a matching condition in a string

Tags: matlab

Hi need help in using regexp for condition matching.

ex.my file has the following content
 {hello.program='function'`;
 bye.program='script'; }

I am trying to use regexp to match the string that has `.program='function'` in them:

```
pattern = '[.program]+\=(function)'
```

also tried `pattern='[^\n]*(.hello=function)[^\n]*';`

```
pattern_match = regexp(myfilename,pattern , 'match')
```

but this returns me pattern_match={} while i expect the result to be hello.program='function'`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `'function'` comes with string-markers, you need to include these in the match. Also, you need to escape the dot (otherwise, it's considered "any character"). `[.program]+` looks for one or several letters contained in the square brackets - but you can just look for `program` instead. Also, you don't need to escape the `=`-sign (which is probably what messed up the match).

```
cst = {'hello.program=''function''';'bye.program=''script'''; };
pat = 'hello\.program=''function''';
out = regexp(cst,pat,'match');
out{1}{1} %# first string from list, first match
   hello.program='function'
```

---

**EDIT**

In response to the comment

> my file contains
>
> m2 = S.Parameter;
>   m2.Value = matlabstandard;
>   m2.Volatility = 'Tunable';
>   m2.Configurability = 'None';
>   m2.ReferenceInterfaceFile ='';
>   m2.DataType = 'auto';
>
> my objective is to find all the lines that match, .DataType='auto'

Here's how you find the matching lines with regexp

```
%# read the file with textscan into a variable txt
fid = fopen('myFile.m');
txt = textscan(fid,'%s');
fclose(fid);
txt = txt{1};

%# find the match. Allow spaces and equal signs between DataType and 'auto'
match = regexp(txt,'\.DataType[ =]+''auto''','match')

%# match is not empty only if a match was found. Identify the non-empty match
matchedLine = find(~cellfun(@isempty,match));
```

Comment: Thanks!but i have to run this on a number of files, and i do not know the exact number of strings they will have.so i cant define them like cst has been. all i know that it should match program=function. i tried using pat = 'hello\.program=''function''';and it returned null:(.any further advice?

Comment: @learningMatlab: I created `cst` just to have something to test - I assumed that your file is read into a cell array of strings. Also, do you need to match `program='function'`, or `program=function`? Or is `'function'` any arbitrary function name?

Comment: function is an arbitrary name. and i need to match .program='function'

Comment: @learningMatlab: say your function names are `something` and `otherThing`. Would your code look like `hello.program=something` or `hello.program='something'`? Could there be spaces around the equal sign?

Comment: @learningMatlab: Can you paste the actual line from the file that you want to be parsed by `regexp`?

Comment: my file contains m2 = S.Parameter;
m2.Value = matlabstandard;
 m2.Volatility = 'Tunable';
m2.Configurability = 'None';
m2.ReferenceInterfaceFile = '';
m2.DataType = 'auto';
my objective is to find all the lines that match, .DataType='auto';

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21098/discussion-between-learningmatlab-and-jonas)

Answer (score 0):

Try this as it matches .program='function' exactly:

```
    (\.)program='function'
```

I think this did not work:

```
    '[.program]+\=(function)'
```

because of how the []'s work.  Here is a link explaining why I say that: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Comment: Thannks.  (\.)program='function' returns null :(

Comment: I tested this at http://www.regextester.com/ and it worked for me successfully there.  Are you running this on a command-line or, perhaps, within an application like BASH or PHP?  Would you mind sharing your exact command with us?

Comment: ...if not, here's all I've got left without being able to test in MATLAB myself: (?:\.)program='[a-zA-Z0-9]+'